# Why can I only see the label on one of my icons in my Bottom Navigation Bar in Android Studio using Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I am trying to develop an app using Android Studio with Flutter and Dart and I need to have a Bottom Navigation Bar with icons corresponding to a page they lead to. I can get the icons showing but only one (Weddings) is labelled. I can't figure out how to get the others have the label displayed on them all the time.

Here is the code I have, any help would be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Whispering Woodz'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Welcome to the Whispering Woodz App!',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.people),
            label: 'Weddings',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Corporate Events',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: 'Matchmaking',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.celebration),
            label: 'Private Parties',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.build),
            label: 'Services Offered',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
            label: 'Gallery',
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (int index) {
          // Handle button taps here
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
            // Wedding Celebrations button tapped
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WeddingPage()));
              break;
            case 1:
            // Corporate Events button tapped
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CorporateEventsPage()));
              break;
            case 2:
            // Match Making button tapped
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MatchMakingPage()));
              break;
            case 3:
            // Private Parties button tapped
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PrivatePartiesPage()));
              break;
            case 4:
            // Services Offered button tapped
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ServicesOfferedPage()));
              break;
            case 5:
            // Gallery button tapped
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GalleryPage()));
              break;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add showUnselectedLabels: true to BottomNavigationBar

Code:

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        fixedColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
    ...
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.